# How to implement custom event triger in a cordova project using hockeyapp

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hockeyapp

How to implement custom event trigger feature in my cordova app using hockeyapp.
I already implement user feedback and crash report feature of hockeyapp.

I am using the code for custom event is

```
hockeyapp.trackEvent(null, null, "EVENT_NAME");
```

It is not working for me..

Comment: Do you have any errors in console ?

Comment: it already shows hockeyapp is not defined. but it is ok with all other features.

Comment: i want a event report when a user enter into the about.html page

Comment: I use the above code in the controller page of about.html

Comment: How did you import hockeyapp ? Did you use a cordova plugin ? If yes, which one ?

Comment: yes, am using a plugin.

Comment: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-hockeyapp@latest

Comment: hockeyapp should not be undefined and it will not work via JavaScript code if it is undefined. Be sure to make any call to hockeyapp after $ionicPlatform.ready event.